# Data showing up in console.log after ajax call but not appearing in custom div in fancybox

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox-2

I appended a custom div with fancybox to display some info regarding the present element. All the data fetches fine. The console log displays exactly what i wished for but somehow the result of the ajax call is shown in the div only once during the first time. The subsequent ajax calls doesnt render anything on the div although i get the right dump in the dev console in chrome.

Where am i going wrong here ?

```
$(".public-gallery").fancybox({
    nextMethod : 'resizeIn',
    nextSpeed  : 250,
    padding : 10,
    beforeLoad: function() {
        this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');
    },
    afterLoad: function(current){

        var description = "<div class='links'><div class='inner' id='resinfo'></div></div>";
        $('.fancybox-overlay').append(description);
        var ref = current.element.data('ref');  
        console.info("ref : " + ref);
         $.post("ajax/fetchresourceinfo.php", {'ref':ref}, function(data){
            $('#resinfo').text("ref:"+ref + data);
            console.info("from here"+data); 
        });
    }});
```

Comment: the html you're setting to variable `description` is malformed, which could be your problem. Look at the closing div tags.

Comment: Sorry but thats a bad typo here. The actual code is pretty fine

<div class='links'><div class='inner' id='resinfo'></div></div>

Comment: could you show your html too?

Comment: The markup is just a normal markup as used in the demos in the fancybox site. Theres nothing wrong in the ajax fetch as i get correct results in the console log.